# Create buttons with a plugin who accept shortcodes?

Tags: plugins

I want to insert buttons with a plugin in my site. But I need plugins who can read shortcodes. Because I have another plugin which create me a shortcodes and I want to insert them into the text fields of the buttons.

And in the end, there should be the output of the shortcode and not just the shortcode text.

Does anyone has an idea which button plugin I could use for that and how can I realise that?

Greetings and Thank You!